# Where is the source of <video> element in webkit, as they are using the shadow dom?

Tags: webkit, shadow-dom

Heard most of the "native" elements, inputs, etc are rendered using shadow DOM. Where can I find the implementation of that shadow DOM in webkit?

Comment: It is probably buried deep in their source code. And it is probably not implemented using JavaScript. Most likely C or C++.

Comment: i'll looking for that exact file :)

Comment: Start here: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/html/HTMLVideoElement.cpp

Comment: Then look here: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/html/VideoDocument.cpp